# sublime 2 rails multi line comments key command

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, sublime-text-2

when coding ruby in sublime text 2, are their key commands for multi line commentS?

```
class Myclass
    include MyMethods
    def instance_method
        puts "hi from the instance method"
        show_inspect
    end
    def self.class_method
        puts "hi from class method"
        show_inspect
    end     
    def Myclass.class_method1
        puts "hi from class method1"
        show_inspect
    end 

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type in your comments, use the MIDDLE CLICK & DRAG to select multiple cursors and then type your # to comment.

Comment: I also found this http://www.pierotoffanin.com/2012/01/sublime-text-2-if-you-havent-tried-it-yet-youre-missing-out/ it appears you can use CTRL + /

Comment: I love ST2. I use it every single day. It truly is the crossplatform Textmate.

Comment: You can also CTRL + LEFT CLICK to place cursors in different locations.

Answer (score 2):

Middle click didn't work for me.

Highlight the lines.
Choose Edit -> Comment -> Toggle Comment
or press CTRL /

Love Submline 2.

Comment: cmd + / works for me